# Pulling the latest code after merging branches

Tags: git

Initially I created a branch out from master and did some commits under the new branch. After which, I have merged it with the master. So now the master holds the latest changes. After that, few changes were done in master by my colleague. I would like my new branch to have the these latest changes in master in it, so I can continue developing in the new branch.

What do I do here? I merge master with new branch? delete the old branch and create a new branch with the same name?

Need some guidance on this. Sorry if this is a noob question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge in either direction. You probably did `git merge newbranch` from the master branch to merge your changes into master. From your new branch you can just do `git merge master` to merge the other way, merging master's latest changes into your new branch.